# Yii2: how to upload two images from two fields in form

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

**Create Function** from the controller:

```
$imageName = $model->primary_name;
// get the uploaded file instance. for multiple file uploads  
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
$model->file->saveAs('uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension);          
//save the path in db
$model->id_image = 'uploads/'.$imageName.'.'.$model->file->extension;

$imageName1 = $model->adult_2_name;
// get the uploaded file instance. for multiple file uploads
$model->file2 = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file2');
$model->file2->saveAs('uploads/adult_2/'.$imageName1.'.'.$model->file2->extension);
//save the path in db
$model->id_image_2 = 'uploads/adult_2/'.$imageName1.'.'.$model->file2->extension;

$model->save();
```

**Model**

```
public $file;
public $file2;

[['file','file2'],'file'],
[['id_image', 'id_image_2'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
```

**View**

```
     <?php

            use yii\helpers\Html;
            /*use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;*/
            use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
            use kartik\file\FileInput;
            use yii\helpers\Url;
            use yii\bootstrap\Modal;

            /* @var $this yii\web\View */
            /* @var $model backend\models\CreateBookings */
            /* @var $form yii\widgets\ActiveForm */
            ?>

 <div class="create-bookings-form">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data'] ]); ?>

<?= Html::activeHiddenInput($model, 'booking_id', ['value' => '' ]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'check_in')->label(false)->input('date', ['placeholder' => '']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'check_out')->label(false)->input('date', ['placeholder' => '']) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'room_type')->label(false)->input('text', ['placeholder' => 'Select Room Type...']) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'primary_name')->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?php $list = ['Male' => 'Male', 'Female' => 'Female'];
    echo $form->field($model, 'gender_1')->label(false)->radioList($list, ['inline'=>true]); ?>
    <?php   echo $form->field($model, 'primary_mobile', ['feedbackIcon' => ['default' => 'phone']])->label(false)->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Enter phone number...']); ?>
    <?php   echo $form->field($model, 'primary_email', [
                            'feedbackIcon' => [
                            'default' => 'envelope',
                            'success' => 'ok',
                            'error' => 'exclamation-sign',
                            'defaultOptions' => ['class'=>'text-primary']
                                ]
                                ])->label(false)->textInput(['placeholder'=>'Enter a valid email address...']); ?>

    <?php echo $form->field($model, 'id_type')->label(false)->dropDownList(['Passport' => 'Passport', 'Aadhar Card' => 'Aadhar Card', 'Driving Licence' => 'Driving Licence','Voter ID' => 'Voter ID',]); ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'id_number')->label(false)->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->label(false)->fileInput(['id'=>'imgfile','onchange' => 'readURL(this)']); ?>                  
    <?php echo '<img id="preview" src="#" width="100" height="100" alt="your image" />' ; ?>                 
    <?= $form->field($model, 'adult_2_name')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(
                    [
                    'id'=>'imgfile2',
                    'onchange' => 'readURL(this)'
                    ]); 
                ?>
    <?= '<img id="preview2" src="#" width="100" height="100" alt="your image" />' ?>

    <div class="form-group">
                    <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ?  'Create' : 'Update', ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
                </div>

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

            </div>

            <?php
            $script = <<< JS

            $("#imgfile").change(function(){
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#preview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                }
            });

            JS;
            $this->registerJs($script);
            ?>
            <?php
            $script = <<< JS

            $("#imgfile2").change(function(){
                if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $('#preview2').attr('src', e.target.result);
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                }
            });

            JS;
            $this->registerJs($script);
            ?>
```

Trying to upload two images in database but not able to make it.

Getting error:

> Call to a member function saveAs() on string

Updated the Active Form....................

Comment: Can you add your model validation rules ? and on your view, you are using 2 different file inputs not just one for multi-uploads, no ?

Comment: I have updated the question, and yes I'm using two different fields to upload these two files.

Comment: Can you show the more of the view including the `ActiveForm`?

Answer (score 0):

change in this line :

```
$model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file2');
```

`$model->file` to `$model->file2`

---

**UPDATE** :

and also on your view file, the second input :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput(
    [ 
      'id'=>'imgfile2',
      'onchange' => 'readURL(this)'
    ]); 
?>
```

should be related to `file2` otherwise you'll be overriding the first uploaded file :

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'file2')->fileInput(
```

Comment: same error message ? Call to a member function saveAs() on string ?

Comment: I first thought that maybe 'file' was a reserved keyword so I tried it, basically the same as you did within a minified version (without any JS code and only the 2 file input fields) and it worked just fine for me, so something else must be wrong in the code, try maybe to remove the JS code temporarily, also you didn't answer my question, if you steel have the same error message : Call to a member function saveAs() on string ?

Comment: got the solution i just need to change the name of file2..and its working now

Comment: Great ! but steel not clear why file2 not working, you did change `$model->file` to `$model->file2` in your controller as mentioned in the first part of my answer, no ?

Comment: `$model->id_image_2` did this